# Numpy operate over multiple duplicated indices

Tags: python, numpy

I want to count items of 2 dimensions array
When I do the incremence by batch indices:

```py
a = np.zeros((3,3))
i = [2,0,2] # indices in axis 0
j = [1,2,1] # indices in axis 1
a[i,j] += 1
```

output

```py
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

**Question**: 
 `a[2,1] += 1` occurs only once because of the duplication of indices. Is there any way to make it occurs multiple times so the result will be

```py
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0.]])
```

Comment: `np.add.at` is required here.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little no-intuitive but `numpy` treats `list`s and `tuple`s differently in indexing for example: `a[[2, 1]] += 1` adds one to rows `1` and `2` whereas `a[(2, 1)] += 1` adds one to cell `(2, 1)`.

In your case, you probably just want

```
a = np.zeros((3,3))
a[[2,0,2],[1,2,1]] += 1
a[(2, 1)] += 1
```